# How can I improve my 'ignore-list' Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, regex, greasemonkey

I cloned an existing GM script that supposedly ignmores users on Simple Machines forums, but it doesn't seem to work --

```
var smf_url = 'http://www.friendsoftom.com/forum/index.php';

var banned = new Array();
banned.push(4268); 

for (var i = 0; i < banned.length; i++){
    var uid = banned[i];
    var url = 'http://friendsoftom.com/forum/index.php?action=profile;u=' + uid;
    var expression = '//tr[td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/b/a[@href = "' + url + '"]]';

    var nodes = document.evaluate(expression, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

    for (var j = 0; j < nodes.snapshotLength; j++) {
        var node = nodes.snapshotItem(j);
        node.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/120908

If you want to clone it for testing, you can test this URI -

http://friendsoftom.com/forum/index.php/topic,8484.0.html

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the script assumes that `action=profile` will be the first query string parameter, but this isn't necessarily the case. Second, your entire expression doesn't select much that's useful. This should get you started:

```
var banned = new Array();
banned.push(4268); 

for (var i = 0; i < banned.length; i++) {
    var uid = banned[i];
    var expression = "id('forumposts')/form[1]/" + 
                "div[starts-with(@class, 'windowbg') " +
                "and descendant::a[contains(@href, 'u=" + uid + "')]]";
    var nodes = document.evaluate(expression, document, null, 
            XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    for (var j = 0; j < nodes.snapshotLength; j++) {
        var node = nodes.snapshotItem(j);
        node.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

You can optimize based on your specific needs, but this seems to solve the problem. In general, I'd recommend building your expression little-by-little. Write to the console in between each new location step, so that you know it's selecting what you want.

Comment: That helps a ton. Thank you lwburk!